# Sorting After Union All

Tags: php, sql, sorting, union

To test these queries I’m running them in the SQL query wizard in Microsoft Access.  I’m trying to modify an existing php file in order to display the high priority status alerts (O and P) at the top which are then ordered by opslogid in a descending order.  After there are no more O and P status alerts I want to display the rest of the status alerts (A, I, R), ordered by opslogid in a descending order.  This is the sample data and required output:

```
tblOpslog

opslogid = 9999, 9998, etc.
status = R, O, I, A, P

opslogid                               status
9999                                       P
9996                                       P
9994                                       O
9991                                       O
9998                                       I
9997                                       I
9980                                       A
9979                                       A
9978                                       A
9930                                       R
9928                                       R
```

My colleague suggested that I use the union all command, which resulted in me coming up with this:

NOTE: THE “WHERE DELETED AND NOVIEW MUST REMAIN IN QUERY, IT IS VITAL IN THE OUTPUT OF THE DATABASE”.  ALSO I CANNOT MAKE ANY CHANGES TO THE DATABASE ITSELF.

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM tblOpslog
Where Deleted = No AND Noview = No AND status in ('O','P'))
union all
select * from (Select * FROM tblOpslog Where Deleted = No AND Noview = No AND status in ('I','R', 'A'))
Order by status, opslogid DESC;
```

The output of this is:

```
opslogid                               status
9980                                       A
9979                                       A
9978                                       A
9998                                       I
9997                                       I
9994                                       O
9991                                       O
9999                                       P
9996                                       P
9930                                       R
9928                                       R
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can someone suggest what to fix/add to the code to display the desired output?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since your ordering of `status` isn't alphabetic, you have to use a CASE expression to control the ordering:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblOpsLog
WHERE Deleted = No AND Noview = No AND status IN ('A', 'I', 'R', 'O', 'P')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN status IN ('O', 'P') then 1
              ELSE 2
         END, opslogid DESC
```

What you tried would have worked in mysql, because it orders each branch of a `UNION` separately. But other SQL engines apply `ORDER BY` to the whole `UNION`.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d3da/2)

Comment: Will that get the output desired? With P and O at the top of the page with their ID's in descending order and then the A, I, R after with their ID's in descending order?  You only addressed the P and O in your statement.

Comment: I handle A, I, R with `ELSE 2`.

Comment: I added something to the `WHERE` clause to ensure we only get those 5 statuses.

Comment: Alright Barmar thanks for your help, I'm going to try this at work tomorrow.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CASE WHEN status IN ('O','P') then 1 ELSE 2 END'.

Comment: Are there any other possible solutions?

Comment: $sql = odbc_exec($odbc," SELECT * FROM tblOpslog Where Deleted = No ".$criteria." AND Noview = No AND status IN ('A', 'I', 'R', 'O', 'P')ORDER BY iif(status IN ('O', 'P'), 1, 2), opslogid DESC") or die (odbc_errormsg());

Can anyone make any suggestions to the code in which I can add a shade of colour to the rows in which the statuses are O and P.

Comment: My syntax works in MySQL or MSSQL. If you're using a different database, you probably have to tweak it. But the basic approach should work.